# How to parse regex with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I have issue with parsing following json

```
"name.regex" : "/^\s*.{1,500}\s*$/"
```

i getting the following exception

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 170
```

Comment: It would be better if you put the entire json string in your question.

Answer (score 0):

i think its about escape char
changing to

```
        "validate.name.expression" : "/^\\s*.{1,500}\\s*$/"
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array('<foo>',"'bar'",'"baz"','&blong&', "\xc3\xa9");

echo "Normal: ",  json_encode($a), "\n";

echo "Tags: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG), "\n";

echo "Apos: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_APOS), "\n";

echo "Quot: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_QUOT), "\n";

echo "Amp: ",     json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_AMP), "\n";

echo "Unicode: ", json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n";

echo "All: ",     json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n\n";
```

Output :

> Normal: ["","'bar'","\"baz\"","&blong&","\u00e9"]
>
> Tags: ["\u003Cfoo\u003E","'bar'","\"baz\"","&blong&","\u00e9"]
>
> Apos: ["","\u0027bar\u0027","\"baz\"","&blong&","\u00e9"]
>
> Quot: ["","'bar'","\u0022baz\u0022","&blong&","\u00e9"]
>
> Amp: ["","'bar'","\"baz\"","\u0026blong\u0026","\u00e9"]
>
> Unicode: ["","'bar'","\"baz\"","&blong&","é"]
>
> All:
>   ["\u003Cfoo\u003E","\u0027bar\u0027","\u0022baz\u0022","\u0026blong\u0026","é"]

Answer (score 0):

`"name.regex" : "/^\s*.{1,500}\s*$/"` is not valid JSON. If that is actually what you are trying to parse, you need to put it in a block to make it valid, then put the block inside a string to pass into `JSON.parse()`.

```
jsonStr = '{"name.regex" : "/^\s*.{1,500}\s*$/"}'
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonStr))
```

But I'm gonna go out on a limb and answer under the assumption that you copy pasted this from somewhere in the middle of a supposedly valid JSON string.

The error is occurring on line 170 because that's when the compiler is no longer able to generate a valid interpretation of the characters it processed. That does not necessarily mean the offending code is on line 170.

You are probably missing a `'` or `"` somewhere in the string you are trying to parse, or maybe even in the block of code before you call JSON.parse().

This is a direct copy paste from a sucessful parse in Chrome dev console.

```
JSON.parse('{"name.regex": "/^\s*.{1,500}\s*$/"}')

>{name.regex: "/^s*.{1,500}s*$/"}
```

No error. So the bug is elsewhere.

As noted in the comment by [aristotll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4680436/aristotll), you should post your entire json string if you still can't find it.